# python selenium send_keys yields wrong character

Tags: python, selenium

I've been running some tests on a remote ubuntu machine and i found a weird bug:

If i try to send any of these keys `%/?^56` to an input, using send_keys, they don't get there.

```
5 creates a backspace
6 creates a Shift+Tab
^ creates a Tab
% creates a backspace
? creates a Enter
```

This only happens on Chrome + Selenium + Python 2.7

```
Selenium is 2.46.0
Chrome is 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
ChromeDriver is 2.15.322488sud
```

Any hints where i could start investigating this?

EDIT: some code i've used to debug this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import string
allchars = string.letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
b1 = Firefox()
b2 = Chrome()
b1.get("http://google.ro")
b2.get("http://google.ro")
i1 = b1.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
i2 = b2.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
for l in allchars:
    i1.send_keys(l)
    i2.send_keys(l)
    time.sleep(1)
    if i1.get_attribute('value') != l:
        print "mismatch",b1,l
    if i2.get_attribute('value') != l:
        print "mismatch",b2,l
    i1.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
    i2.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

EDIT2: After upgrading the packages to the latest version available for ubuntu-x64, the problem persisted, but only for these characters `%/?5`. I'm going to post this to the bugtracker.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also, is it reproducible with Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: I've got this problem even on google search. Firefox works okay. Currently trying to find newer packages.

Comment: If this is a reliably reproducible bug, why not treat it as such? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues

Comment: all goes well in my computer: win7+py2.7+chrome'43.0.2357.124', BTW, the url I entered: `https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=ssl`